# High temperatures from sensors on Asus Zenbook UX501 VW

Tags: nvidia, uefi, encryption, temperature, nvidia-prime

I bought a new laptop: Asus Zenbook UX501VW, i7, 24GB RAM, 512 SSD, Intel Graphics + Geforce 960M.

`sensors` returns this:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +65.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +64.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +64.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +56.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +54.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +55.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:     3300 RPM
temp1:        +65.0°C
```

Is this normal for this ultrabook? System is updated, installed nvidia-prime (due to two graphic cards) running on Intel profile (power saving mode). GRUB has:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force drm.vblankoffdelay=1 i915.semaphores=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

System is Kubuntu 16.04 64bit with encrypted home, no swap (too much RAM). Clean and updated without extra personal apps. These temperatures are after login, with nothing else running.

For example on my old Dell Latitude also i7, 16GB RAM, SSD 512, overloaded with skype, web browser, running music player and much other apps, temperatures are around 40-45. The only differcence is that the Dell is running on Kubuntu 14.04 64bit and doesn't have dedicated nvidia card and doesn't have encrypted home (but has partition encrypted with LUKS). **What I see in task manager is that process kworker/0:2 is always consuming 12% CPU** on Dell all are 0%. Ahh and this is the first time when I have Ubuntu on UEFI (just didn't remove uefi partition).

Dir `/sys/firmware/efi` exists

Comment: I do not see anything wrong.

Comment: Temperatures around 55-65 in idle mode (empty desktop after boot) is not wrong?

Comment: It depends on hardware and outside temp. Nothing extraordinary.

Comment: Have Dell Latitude E7440 with similar hardware in same room. Working on it now, sensors report 40-45C and something called adapter virtual device (graphic card?) has 23C (on asus same device has 65C). Nvidia card should be off so running on intel vga same as Dell. Don't kno why such abnormal temperatures. Must check why kworker consuming 12% CPU, maybe here is answer

Comment: @Dibo I have a Latitude E6500 that reports 68C idle and three desktops that report temp. ranges between 38C and 84C depending on which machine and what it does.  My Inspiron 15R Special edition averages 72C idling on OpenVPN and wireshark-ing network traffic.  There is nothing wrong with the temps you are seeing, I think, as all laptops / ultra books run hotter than their desktop counterparts.  Worry when your system starts idling at 85C - 90C consistently.

Comment: @Thomas. My Latitude is also ultrabook and I don't know when I heard fan last time, probably weeks ago when rendered movie in openshot. Even with watching fullhd movies, dell is cold and fan not start. When I saw temperatures above 55C then it meant that some process took 25% of one core. On new Asus, 55C is in normal idle state and fan is always noiseing (not loud, just little noise). I'm worrying what it will be when I start work on it. Maybe I'm just used to my Latitude and have to adjust to the new hardware where humming fan and temperatures above 55C are just normal

Comment: Guys! Solved! Yesterday before sleep, played with KDE system settings. Changed render engine from OpenGL 2.0 to XRender. Today I run Asus. Finally kworkers are consuming 0% CPU. Fan is off, browsing web for about 20 minutes, all temperatures around 35-38C. Never was so happy

Comment: Check cpufreq too, may be adjustable to a lower & cooler frequency.  And `sensors` may not be reporting accurately, compared it with bios & manufacturer provided utilities (probably for win)?